# MySQL: Changing column type and date time format

Tags: mysql, sql

My DB currently have 'date' column setup as varchar(20) and I date is formatted like this:

```
1/13/2015 20:00
```

I would like to run an update on my DB to change column type to datetime and change format of my current date to something more typical like

```
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi
```

Can this be done in MySQL?

Comment: No that not the answer  @community. He need's to use [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function

Comment: I can see that within the comments, but would be great if someone would post full answer with [STR_TO_DATE]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ***[`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)*** function

> This is the inverse of the DATE_FORMAT() function. It takes a string
>   str and a format string format. STR_TO_DATE() returns a DATETIME value
>   if the format string contains both date and time parts, or a DATE or
>   TIME value if the string contains only date or time parts. If the
>   date, time, or datetime value extracted from str is illegal,
>   STR_TO_DATE() returns NULL and produces a warning.

To view the *converted* dates

```
select str_to_date(date_column, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i') 
from tablename
```

Make sure everything is fine then run `update` statement

```
update tablename set date_column = str_to_date(date_column, '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i')
```

Its better to store `datetime` data in `datetime` datatype

```
Alter table tablename modify column date_column datetime
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done in mysql. Since your existing data is not compatible with mysql's datetime format, you can't do it in one step, though.

1. Change your text data to mysql's native datetime format (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss) using [str_to_date()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function in an update statement.
2. Use [ALTER TABLE ... MODIFY COLUMN ...](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) command to change the data type of the column to datetime.

> Warning This conversion may result in alteration of data. For example,
>   if you shorten a string column, values may be truncated. To prevent
>   the operation from succeeding if conversions to the new data type
>   would result in loss of data, enable strict SQL mode before using
>   ALTER TABLE (see Section 5.1.7, “Server SQL Modes”).

The 1st step is to take care of data conversion issues, however, it is good practice to enable strict sql mode before the 2nd step. If you are unsure, then create another datetime column and update its values using str_to_date() to see the original and converted values side by side.